# iFrame height resize

Tags: iframe, resize, autoscroll

Need to change frame height to page content.
In frame will be a comment block.
Sorry 4 my english :P
Problem is [HERE](http://salat-production.ru/g_random.html).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
$(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
$(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"800px", height:"75%"});
$(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"1057px", height:"750px"});
$("#click").click(function(){ 
$('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text;
return false;
});
});
</script>

<a class='iframe' href="Gallery/complete/photo0001489_61132.html"><img src="Gallery/complete/min/1.jpg" width="200px"></a>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in text or document with screenshots, for once the publem is fixed it the provided link won't help future visitors to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you're asking for but this should do the trick if you are using jQuery:

```
 $('.element').height($('.other-element').height());
```

also you can do

```
 $('.element').css({
'height':$('.other-element').height()
});
```

Comment: @user1791020 nice girl :D .. joking .. as i understand you should try my code **.element** in your case is the **iframe** element then you can use also css **overflow:hidden;** if you do not want to show scrollbars